# How to tell SwiftUI KeyPathComparator is in increasing or decreasing order?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I followed [SwiftUI Table Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table) "Supporting sorting in tables" section to make my table sortable and store its order value in a variable. However, I don't know how to check if this order value is in increasing order or decreasing order, then I cannot save the correct order in UserDefaults.

I'd like to do something like shown below. How can I make it?

```
@Published var sortOrder: [KeyPathComparator<Song>] = []

...

Button("Save Sort Order") {
    if let newOrder = sortOrder.first {
        if newOrder == KeyPathComparator(\Song.titleValue).increasingOrder // To check its order, some code like this
        { /* Store "Title-Increasing" */ }
        if newOrder == KeyPathComparator(\Song.titleValue).decreasingOrder // To check its order, some code like this
        { /* Store "Title-Decreasing" */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: `newOrder == KeyPathComparator(\Song.titleValue).isIncreasing` doesn't make sense? You are equating a `KeyPathComparator` and a `Bool`. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry for my poor expression, I'll edit my post to make it more logical

Comment: This will not be easy to maintain if you have multiple sortable columns in your table.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's true. But maybe it can help that save KeyPath ("Title") and SortOrder ("Increasing") in 2 UserDefaults separately.

Comment: But you need to know which value belongs to which column, remember that `sortOrder` is an array so it will contain multiple elements if you have clicked the header of more than one sortable column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyPathComparator` has an `order: SortOrder` property that tells you if the order is `forward` or `backward`.

You can store that value.